# Edit text file programmatically

Tags: android

How can we modify a text file from android, such as

- append at the end of the file.
- clear data at any intermediate position and also blank lines in it.

Is there any option to delete a particular line from the text file, I read so many tutorials regarding this all have mentioned to create a temporary file and asked to copy the contents from the original file except that particular line, and to replace the original file with this temporary file.
Is there any alternative to do this with in that original file itself without creating a temporary file?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the second option programmatically, that's virtually impossible. The first option however is possible. Just use an `InputStream Object` to load your file, then you can get the text from the `InputStream` as a String, I believe, and then you can append the data at the end. Now that I think of it, it might be possible, but with a heck of a lot of work, to edit the text at the middle... But that's up to you to figure out...

Comment: Why cant you do the second option  >_< its not impossible

Comment: Sorry, wasn't finished typing yet >.< re-edited the answer ;p

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everything that is [possible](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) with java's [file api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)'s can be done in [android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29), passing true for `append` and then using the normal output stream operations.

For changing files in a random-access manner, try [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).  This allows you to change the current byte you are pointing to.  However, if you delete data in this manner it won't automatically cause the file to contract to fill the empty space; you would need to do this manually and then change the length of the file via `setLength()`.